# Can't connect to localhost after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: apache, server, localhost

After updating to El Capitan I can't access localhost.

Another computer where El Capitan was already at the installation of  MAMP everything works fine.

Both Apache and MySQL server start ,but can't get to localhost page
This is what I've tried so far:
1) Uncommented  some of the lines on httpd.conf as indicated on some messages
2) Replaced current files with files in private/etc/apache2/original
3) Copied http.conf and extra/ from the other computer (the one where localhost is working)
4) Tried different ports configuration (Apache: 8888 & MySql: 8889)
Since none of the above worked, I put back files to the original state (i.e. before uncommenting or replacing)

Finally, if instead of localhost I type computer_name.local/ on the browser address bar I can see my files.

I am VERY new with all this, any suggestions?
Thanks,

S

Denis, thanks for the suggestion. These are the results from Terminal:
    lo0: flags=8049 mtu 16384
    options=3
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1
    gif0: flags=8010 mtu 1280
    stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
    en1: flags=8823 mtu 1500
    ether 88:63:df:cb:a5:39 
    nd6 options=1
    media: autoselect ()
    status: inactive
    en0: flags=8863 mtu 1500
    options=10b
    ether ac:87:a3:14:72:1b 
    nd6 options=1
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
    en2: flags=963 mtu 1500
    options=60
    ether 0a:00:00:3c:bc:00 
    media: autoselect 
    status: inactive
    en3: flags=963 mtu 1500
    options=60
    ether 0a:00:00:3c:bc:01 
    media: autoselect 
    status: inactive
    en5: flags=8863 mtu 1500
    options=10b
    ether 40:6c:8f:38:4f:a5 
    inet6 fe80::426c:8fff:fe38:4fa5%en5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
    inet 192.168.1.21 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=1
    media: autoselect (1000baseT )
    status: active
    en7: flags=8863 mtu 1460
    ether 02:50:f2:00:00:01 
    nd6 options=1
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
    p2p0: flags=8802 mtu 2304
    ether 0a:63:df:cb:a5:39 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
    bridge0: flags=8863 mtu 1500
    options=63
    ether 8a:63:df:bc:63:00 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en2 flags=3
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 7 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1
    media: 
    status: inactive
    awdl0: flags=8902 mtu 1484
    ether 52:4f:2b:35:96:9d 
    nd6 options=1
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive

Comment: type 

    ifconfig -a

in your terminal and check your localhost Loopback
or post your results in this thread please

Comment: The Apache log shows this error
[error] [client 192.168.1.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
Permissions seem to be correct Owner (Me), Admin Read & Write, Everyone Read Only

Comment: Additional errors from Apache:
-- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 31 10:48:26 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jul 31 10:48:34 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 31 10:48:34 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Jul 31 10:48:34 2016] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 58475)
[Sun Jul 31 10:48:34 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 PHP/7.0.8 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2h DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured

Comment: after trying different things I've solved the problem - the issue was the presence of additional DNS server on the Mac network settings. After deleting the additional entries and leaving only the router ip address everything seems to be working fine.